# Prove that $\operatorname{null}(A)+\operatorname{null}(B)≥\operatorname{null}(AB)$ in matrix formulation

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

I've already seen [this question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1600861/prove-that-operatornamenull-a-operatornamenull-b-ge-operatornamenul), but I'd like to prove the case in a matrix form as below; however, I have no justification for a particular part of my proof:

Let $A_{m*n}$, and $B_{n*k}$, so $AB_{m*k}$.

According to the rank-nullity theorem, we have:

$n(A) + r(A) = n$

$n(B) + r(B) = k$

$n(AB) + r(AB) = k$

Adding the first two equations and using the third one to get rid of $k$ yields:

$n(A) + n(B) + r(A) +r(B) = n + n(AB) + r(AB)$

Since $r(B) \ge r(AB)$, we have

$n(A) + n(B) + r(A) \le n + n(AB)$

Here is the problem: I know that $r(A) \le n$, so I can't justify how to eliminate $r(A)$ and $n$ to end up with

$n(A) + n(B) \ge n(AB)$

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not without linear maps, but different from the proof in the other question.

You had this:

$$n(A) + n(B) + r(A) +r(B) = n + n(AB) + r(AB)$$

Rearranging gives:

$$n(A) + n(B) - n(AB) = r(AB) - r(A) - r(B) + n$$

so to prove the desired inequality, it is sufficient to prove $r(AB) - r(A) - r(B) + n\ge 0$.

Consider the linear map $A|_{\operatorname{Im} B} : \operatorname{Im} B \to \operatorname{Im} A$, the restriction of $A$ to $\operatorname{Im} B$.

Using the rank-nullity theorem for $A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}$ we obtain:

$$r(B) = \dim\operatorname{Im} B = n\left(A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}\right) + r\left(A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}\right)$$

Notice that $n\left(A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}\right) \le n(A)$, and that $r\left(A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}\right) = r(AB)$.

$$r(B) =  n\left(A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}\right) + r\left(A|_{\operatorname{Im} B}\right) \le n(A) + r(AB) = n - r(A) + r(AB)$$

Rearranging gives $r(AB) - r(A) - r(B) + n\ge 0$, so we have $n(A) + n(B) - n(AB) \ge 0$.

Answer (score 2):

What you are trying is not likely to work. You have numbers
\begin{align}
a+b&=n \\ 
c+d&=k \\
e+f&= k
\end{align}
with $d\geq f$, $b\geq f$, $a\leq e$, $c\leq e$. All those relations are not enough to obtain your implication. Consider for instance
\begin{align}
1+4&=5 \\ 
1+4&=5 \\
3+2&= 5
\end{align}
Then all relations are satisfied but $1+1<3$. You need more information to obtain your inequality.

Comment: Can you please be a little bit explicit on that "more information"?

Comment: What you noted clarifies that my logic is flawed (as I already felt so asked this question). Now, the question is how I should fix this case.

Comment: I don't know. You want to prove the inequality without using that $A$ and $B$ are operators. My example shows that you cannot expect to obtain the inequality from the information you tried to use. Other than that, I'm not sure. The proof I know is the one you don't want to use.

Comment: By "the proof I know", you mean the one whose link is in the question? If you mean something else, can you please add you proof to the answer?

Comment: I mean exactly the one linked in the question.